# Как включить комментарии в произвольном типе поста в теме MIES?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, post

У меня есть тема mies и у меня недавно возникла задача вывести комментарии для произвольного типа поста зашитого в комментарии.
Я добавил в класс регистрации поддержку комментариев и сам шаблон Comments в content-mies_portfolio.php.
Однако там он не выводит форму. Так же в админке не позволяет разрешить комментарии.
Подскажите, куда копать?

http://themeforest.net/item/mies-an-avantgarde-architecture-wordpress-theme/9797892

Comment: Спасибо Александр.

Comment: Read The Code Luke